# Time complexity of a triple nested loop with squared indices

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I have seen this function in past year exam paper.

```
public static void run(int n){
    for(int i = 1 ; i * i < n ; i++){
        for(int j = i ; j * j < n ; j++){
            for(int k = j ; k * k < n ; k++){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

After give some example, I guess it is a function that with time complexity in following formula

***let make m = n^(1/2)***

***[m+(m-1)+(m-2)+...+3+2+1] + [(m-1)+(m-2)+...+3+2+1] + ...... + (3+2+1) + (2+1) + 1***

*Edit: I have asked this math question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/159142/33103), the answer is **m(m+1)(m+2)/6**

Is this correct, if no, what is wrong, if yes, how would you translate to big O notation.
The question that I want to ask is not **only** about this specific example; but also how would you evaluate an algorithm, let's say, I can only give some example to watch the pattern it appears. But some algorithm are not that easy to evaluate, what is your way to evaluate using this example.

**Edit:
@LuchianGrigore
@AleksG**

```
public static void run(int n){
        for(int i = 1 ; i * i < n ; i++){
            for(int j = 1 ; j * j < n ; j++){
                for(int k = 1 ; k * k < n ; k++){

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is an example that in my lecture notes, each loop is with time complexity of **n** to the power of **1/2**, for each loop there is another n^(1/2) inside, the total are n^(1/2) * n^(1/2) * n^(1/2) = n^(3/2).
Is the first example the same? It is less than the second example, right?

**Edit,Add:**

How about this one? Is it **log(n)*n^(1/2)*log(n^2)**

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)
            for (int j = i; j * j < n; j++)
                for (int m = j; j < n * n; j *= 2)
```

Comment: What is the actual question here? Please restrict your self to *one* question.

Comment: Each of the loops runs $\sqrt{n}$ times, for a total of $O(n^{3/2})$

Comment: The last example is likely not doing what the thread starter thinks it does, and has complexity of O ((log n)^2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one of the loops, you've a complexity of $O(\sqrt n)$. You're nesting the loops three times, so you'll get the complexity of $O(\sqrt n^3)$, which is $O(n^{3/2})$.

If you want to be more precise, then for your original question, the complexity will be:

1. $O(\sqrt n)$ for the first loop
2. $O(\sqrt n - 1)$ for the second loop, which is the same as $O(\sqrt n)$, since the time complexity of `1` is constant.
3. $O(\sqrt n - 2)$ for the third loop, which is the same as $O(\sqrt n)$, since the time complexity of `2` is constant.

Therefore, the total complexity is still $O(\sqrt n^3) = O(n^{3/2})$.

**EDIT/ADD:**

You're pretty much correct, just make one more step to simplify the expression, remembering that $\log(n^2) = 2 \times \log(n)$.  There are three loops:

1. The first on is, correctly, $O(\log n)$.
2. The second one is just like in the first problem, so you get $O(\sqrt n)$.
3. The third one is on the square of $n$, therefore you get $O(\log(n^2))$, which is the same as $O(2\log(n))$, which is the same as $O(\log(n))$.

Combining the three, it's pretty much like a multiplication, you will get: $O(\log(n) \times \sqrt n \times \log(n))$, which is $O(\log(n)^2 \times \sqrt n)$.

Comment: Edited, Sorry but I agree that first loop is O(n^(1/2)), but the 2nd & 3rd loop are not start from 1, but i & j. Is it still the same?

Comment: @null Yes, you still will receive the same overall O-complexity.  See my edit

Comment: @null The reason behind this is the following: Let's say we have only two nested loops. The inner loop starts at 1 for the first iteration of the outer loop, at 2 for the second iteration, ..., at sqrt(n) for the last iteration of the outer loop. So on average, it starts at around sqrt(n)/2 and ends at sqrt(n), which makes it `O(sqrt(n)/2)=O(sqrt(n))` (the same as the outer loop).

Comment: @AleksG since I have asked so many, would you mind to take a look at the added one, is it correct?

Comment: @brimborium thanks, only care about the one with significant performance affect. so O(N^3+N^2+N) = O(N^3), right? Would you mind to take a look at the added example. Is my answer correct?

Comment: Note that you actually have $\Theta$ everywhere, which is probably what is desired.

Comment: @Raphael hi,what does that mean?

Comment: @null: See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use/61#61).